# How to add this data to array ? Json

Tags: php, json

I have an array as such

```
$array = array{
               'title' => "happy"
              }
```

When i use Json encode, i get :

```
{"title":"happy"}
```

Later on in my code, i need to add some items in the $array like "Gender"

```
$array[] = array{
                'Gender' => $gender
               }
```

When i use Json encode, it becomes something like:

```
{"title":"happy","0":{"Gender":"female"}}
```

I really don't want the "0". I just want it to be :

```
{"title":"happy","Gender":"female"}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a *new* array and then appending it to the end of the existing array.

You just want to add a new key to the existing array:

```
$array['Gender'] = $gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
$array = array('title' => "happy");
$array['Gender'] = $gender;
json_encode($array);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/QTLa0lSE)**

Answer (score 0):

First you assign a filled array to `$array`. Later you add another array to the existing array.

Creating an array with content:

```
$array = array(
    'title' => 'happpy'
);
```

Is the same as:

```
$array = array();
$array['title'] = 'happy';
```

When adding an extra value to the array you need to:

```
$array['gender'] = 'Your gender';
```

After the full array is created you can `json_encode` it.

**Tip:**
Merge two existing arrays by using the function [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[] = array('title' => "happy");
echo json_encode($array)."</br>";
//outputs : [{"title":"happy"}]
$array[] = array('Gender' => "female");
echo json_encode($array)."</br>";
//outputs :[{"title":"happy"},{"Gender":null}]
```